# Is it wrong to print $/ instead of \n?

Tags: perl, newline

Perl's documentation says that `$/` is:

> The input record separator, newline by default. This influences Perl's
>   idea of what a "line" is.

So, is it basically wrong to:

```perl
print STDERR $var, $/;
```

instead of:

```perl
print STDERR "$var\n";
```

?

What could go wrong if I do the former?

Comment: It is the *input* separator which might be manipulated if you need to read CRLF or CR encoded files.

Comment: `$/` is the system eol character, which is fine if the file you're generating is only for "Local" usage. If you're generating a file for some OTHER os, e.g. you're on Linux building a Windows file, then `$/` is useless.

Comment: You should really use the *output* record separator ``$\``, but I can't see anything wrong with doing that. In fact, the [`say` function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/say.html) does just this: "`say LIST` is simply an abbreviation for `{ local $\ = "\n"; print LIST }`" (If you're on 5.10+, I would just use `say` instead.)

Comment: Marc's comment is totally correct! $/ refers to the default system eol character. You can change it according to the context in which you are using it.

Comment: @user3476791: No, Perl does its best to hide the system eol character (or sequence) and present it as linefeed `"\n"` to your Perl code. Manipulating `$/` is used when the input records that you want to retrieve with the `<>` operator don't coincide with lines of text. That's why it's called *input record separator* and not *input line separator*

Comment: @Borodin is correct, Mark B is wrong.  `$/` defaults to "\n" on any system; CRLF translation is usually dealt with in the I/O functions, so your code only ever sees/produces "\n"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for the output record separator instead?

> [perldoc perlvar](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlvar#OUTPUT_FIELD_SEPARATOR):
>
> ```
>  IO::Handle->output_record_separator( EXPR )
>    $OUTPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR
>    $ORS
>    $\
> ```
>
> The output record separator for the print operator.
>   If defined, this value is printed after the last of print's arguments.  Default is "undef".
>
> You cannot call "output_record_separator()" on a handle, only as a static method. See [IO::Handle](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Handle).
>
> Mnemonic: you set "`$\`" instead of adding "`\n`" at the end of the print. Also, it's just like `$/`, but it's what you get "back" from Perl.

For example,

```
$\ = $/;
print STDERR $var;
```

Comment: I think this is a very bad idea. Not many modules protect themselves against `$\ ` getting changed, so globally changing `$\ ` will break them. You could limit the scope of the change using `{ local $\ = $/; print STDERR $var; }`, but that's a complete mess compared to `print STDERR "$var\n";` or `say STDERR $var;`.

Comment: @ikegami And I think that if modules can't handle `$\­` getting changed, that's a bug in the modules, especially considering there's a commonly-used command-line option that does set `$\­` (`-l`).

Comment: @hvd, Commonly-used in one-liners, maybe, but I suspect that very few module do `local $/;` before every `print` because it would be silly to do that, even if you consider it a bug.

Answer (score 7):

`$/` is LF (U+000A) by default. This is the same character produced by `"\n"`<sup>[1]</sup>. So unless you changed `$/`, `$/` and `"\n"` are equivalent. If you did change `$/`, then only you know why, and therefore only you know whether `$/` or `"\n"` is more appropriate.

---

1. On ancient MacOS boxes, `$/`'s default was CR (U+000D), but that's also what `"\n"` produced there.

Answer (score 1):

You need output record separator $\ as [xxfelixxx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1799189/xxfelixxx) has answered.

`$/` as you read is `input record separator`. Manipulating it can affect how Perl reads the file data you've provided. For example:

```
open my $fh, "<", $filename or die $!;
local $/; # enable localized slurp mode
my $content = <$fh>;
close $fh;
```

The above causes whole content of file to slurp in scalar $content because we had reset `$/`.

Consider the below code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $content;
{local $/; $content = <DATA>}
print "Content is $content";
__DATA__
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

Output:

```
Content is line 1
line 2
line 3
```

But if you do not reset $/, like in below code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $content = <DATA>;
print "Content is $content";
__DATA__
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

Output will be `Content is line 1`.

This is because the input record separator was set to newline and it returned after first line.